# How to Save Array Value after the submit the form in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am Create a Quiz System.In Quiz system I show One Question on One Page.When User Click the next button its show the the next Question.The Problem is, I store the all question in array.when user click the next button the question array remove the question and show the error .The Question variable is not defined.

```
**Below code Assign the All Question in array**
<?php 
    if(!isset($_SESSION["index"]))
    {
        $_SESSION["index"]=0;
        $i=$_SESSION["index"];
        //Function Call Find all question
        $Questions=Find_All_Question_BY_Quiz_ID($Quiz_Item["Quiz_Item_ID"]);
        //$Declare the array;
        static $Question=array();
        while($Questionss=mysqli_fetch_assoc($Questions))
        {  
            $Question[]=$Questionss;
            $index++;
            echo $index;
        }
        $i=$_SESSION["index"]+1;
        echo "1:index+1 is equal to  ".$i;
        $Quiz=Show_One_By_One_Question($Question);
        echo $Quiz;
    }
    else
    {
        //Its craete function show question in html form
        $Quiz=Show_One_By_One_Question($Question);
        echo $Quiz;
        $_SESSION["index"]=0;
    }
?>
```

**Below Code Show the Output**

```
<form action="QuizPage.php">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Click me">
</form>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is doing that because you are not defining your `$question` variable withing your `else` block.  So, your first request to page, sets it, but for the second request, it is not set.  Maybe you should store the question in the session as well.

Comment: How to store $Question in session whenever $Question is array.

Comment: It's the same regardless of type.  So do: `$_SESSION["question"] = $Question;`.  Then in your `else` block, you can do `$Question = $_SESSION["question"];`